# Magento 1: Which ACL is related to the editor handle?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, user-roles, acl, update-handle

I'm using the following observer to add the `editor` handle to a **System > Configuration** section:

Partial `config.xml`:

```
<adminhtml>
    <!-- Events -->
    <events>
        <!-- Triggered before layout load -->
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <digitalpianism_test_controller_action_layout_load_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>test/admin_observer</class>
                    <method>addEditorHandle</method>
                </digitalpianism_test_controller_action_layout_load_before>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then my `Admin/Observer.php` file looks like this:

```
class DigitalPianism_Wall2time_Model_Admin_Observer
{
    /**
     * Add the editor handle to the system configuration Test section
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function addEditorHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $params = $observer->getAction()->getRequest()->getParams();
        // We add the editor handle when viewing the section where the chooser widget is displayed
        if (array_key_exists('section',$params) && $params['section'] == "test")
        {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('editor');
        }
    }
}
```

**That works perfectly fine as a full administrator**, I can use the editor handle to use widget in that specific section of my module.

However, if I use an user with a role limited to the System > Configuration > Test section only, I get the following error in the JS console:

> ReferenceError: WysiwygWidget is not defined

When I check the resources loaded, I find that **the `mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js` is not getting loaded from the `editor` handle**, I assume it has something to do with the resources I assigned to my user role but I can't find ***which ACL is related to this specific `editor` handle***.

NB: **user allowed with another configuration section allowed access won't face the problem**, it only happens if the user can only access the *System > Configuration > Test* section.

Comment: Interesting question. I thought, layout and ACL were not coupled at all but I found that you can add a ACL restriction to `<remove>` elements: `<remove name="BLOCKNAME" acl="RESOURCE" />` only removes the block if the user has permissions for RESOURCE. But the remove tag seems to be the only one and has nothing to do with the editor handle.

Comment: Actually it seems to be the other way around: if a block has an acl attribute it may not be removed. Weird.

Comment: But that still does not help you. The problem must be somewhere else. I'm sure, other pages with the editor handle work with restricted users.

Comment: @fschmengler you made interesting points, even if that does not help for this problem, it enlighted me on some mechanisms I wasn't aware of. I'm about to do more tests today, I'll update my question when I find more details

Comment: @fschmengler it was hard but I've found the root of my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deep into the code, here is what I've found:

The original problem is caused by the fact that with a **user using a role only limited to a specific System > Configuration section**, when you log in, you *land directly on the corresponding System > Configuration section* page with an URL that looks like this:

```
http://www.shop.com/index.php/admin/system_config/index/key/...
```

Because of this, the **following condition in my `Observer.php` is not true** as no parameters have been set:

```
if (array_key_exists('section',$params) && $params['section'] == "test")
{
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('editor');
}
```

> Now **why is there no parameters set and why I still can land on the
>   right section of my configuration page** ?

Well, that was a tough one, it's definitely related to ACL as I guessed, and I assumed it was somehow triggered in a controller or via an observer.

Here is the relevant code of `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php` in the `editAction` method:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')
        ->setSection($current)
        ->setWebsite($website)
        ->setStore($store);

$configFields = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config');

$sections     = $configFields->getSections($current);
$section      = $sections->$current;
```

Even if that looks like it is what we're looking for, it's totally not. The `$sections` variable contains every single system configuration section, no restriction based on the admin user have been applied yet.
On top of that, the `$current` and thus `$section` are empty.

> Well, no luck here! So how do I land on my section??

I'll save you the time spent looking for the file that was handling all this magic: `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Tabs.php`!

> Well what ? A block is handling the ACL ?

Yep, here is the code under the `initTabs` method:

```
foreach ($sections as $section) {
    ...
    $sectionAllowed = $this->checkSectionPermissions($code);
    if ((empty($current) && $sectionAllowed)) {

       $current = $code;
       $this->getRequest()->setParam('section', $current);
    }
    ...
}
```

To summarize:

- The `ConfigController.php` mentioned above first checks if a section is set in the parameters (a tab has been clicked basically).
- It then loads the layout (my `Observer.php` is getting triggered without luck)
- Then it appends the `adminhtml/system_config_tabs` to the left block and calls the `initTabs` method
- Only now the section parameter is added after looping through every single section of the configuration and keeping only the allowed ones.

Final answer: there is **no way to add the `editor` handle via an Observer to a System Configuration section for a user role only limited to that section**.

Alternative solutions:

We can **change the condition under the `Observer.php` file so the `editor` handle is added for every section of the configuration**:

```
if ($observer->getAction()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == "system_config")
{
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('editor');
}
```

Or we change the user role so it is **allowed to see an upper section of the configuration**, thus, the **user always land on this upper section and when he/she clicks the tab where we want to add the `editor` handle, the parameter is added and the handle is added**.